# I need help traversing a hiearchy with a recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion, animation, gltf

Im currently working on animating a model in my gameengine. the fileformat i'm working with is GLTF.

I've come like 90% into actually performing the animation.

Now to the last bit of problem:

i have this hiearchy of bones in my model:

```
_rootJoint, boneID: 0, NodeID: 5
 hips_JNT_01, boneID: 1, NodeID: 7
  spine_JNT_02, boneID: 2, NodeID: 8
  spine1_JNT_03, boneID: 3, NodeID: 9
    spine2_JNT_04, boneID: 4, NodeID: 10
      neck_JNT_05, boneID: 5, NodeID: 11
        head_JNT_06, boneID: 6, NodeID: 12
      l_shoulder_JNT_07, boneID: 7, NodeID: 13
        l_arm_JNT_08, boneID: 8, NodeID: 14
          l_forearm_JNT_09, boneID: 9, NodeID: 15
            l_hand_JNT_010, boneID: 10, NodeID: 16
              l_handThumb1_JNT_00, boneID: 11, NodeID: 17
                l_handThumb2_JNT_011, boneID: 12, NodeID: 18
                  l_handThumb3_JNT_012, boneID: 13, NodeID: 19
              l_handIndex1_JNT_013, boneID: 14, NodeID: 20
                l_handIndex2_JNT_014, boneID: 15, NodeID: 21
                  l_handIndex3_JNT_015, boneID: 16, NodeID: 22
              l_handMiddle1_JNT_016, boneID: 17, NodeID: 23
                l_handMiddle2_JNT_017, boneID: 18, NodeID: 24
                  l_handMiddle3_JNT_018, boneID: 19, NodeID: 25
              l_handRing1_JNT_019, boneID: 20, NodeID: 26
                l_handRing2_JNT_020, boneID: 21, NodeID: 27
                  l_handRing3_JNT_021, boneID: 22, NodeID: 28
              l_handPinky1_JNT_022, boneID: 23, NodeID: 29
                l_handPinky2_JNT_023, boneID: 24, NodeID: 30
                  l_handPinky3_JNT_024, boneID: 25, NodeID: 31
      r_shoulder_JNT_025, boneID: 26, NodeID: 32
        r_arm_JNT_026, boneID: 27, NodeID: 33
          r_forearm_JNT_027, boneID: 28, NodeID: 34
            r_hand_JNT_028, boneID: 29, NodeID: 35
              r_handThumb1_JNT_029, boneID: 30, NodeID: 36
                r_handThumb2_JNT_030, boneID: 31, NodeID: 37
                  r_handThumb3_JNT_031, boneID: 32, NodeID: 38
              r_handIndex1_JNT_032, boneID: 33, NodeID: 39
                r_handIndex2_JNT_033, boneID: 34, NodeID: 40
                  r_handIndex3_JNT_034, boneID: 35, NodeID: 41
              r_handMiddle1_JNT_035, boneID: 36, NodeID: 42
                r_handMiddle2_JNT_036, boneID: 37, NodeID: 43
                  r_handMiddle3_JNT_037, boneID: 38, NodeID: 44
              r_handRing1_JNT_038, boneID: 39, NodeID: 45
                r_handRing2_JNT_039, boneID: 40, NodeID: 46
                  r_handRing3_JNT_040, boneID: 41, NodeID: 47
              r_handPinky1_JNT_041, boneID: 42, NodeID: 48
                r_handPinky2_JNT_042, boneID: 43, NodeID: 49
                  r_handPinky3_JNT_043, boneID: 44, NodeID: 50
l_upleg_JNT_044, boneID: 45, NodeID: 51
  l_leg_JNT_045, boneID: 46, NodeID: 52
    l_foot_JNT_046, boneID: 47, NodeID: 53
      l_toebase_JNT_047, boneID: 48, NodeID: 54
r_upleg_JNT_048, boneID: 49, NodeID: 55
  r_leg_JNT_049, boneID: 50, NodeID: 56
    r_foot_JNT_050, boneID: 51, NodeID: 57
      r_toebase_JNT_051, boneID: 52, NodeID: 58
```

Now to update and calculate the global transform of each bone im using a recursive function:

```
void CalculateBoneTransform(Bone *bone, int depth)
{
    // skip _rootjoint(bone)
    if (bone->id != 0)
    {
        bone->Update(m_CurrentTime);

        for (auto child : bone->children)
        {
            bone->parent->globalTransform = bone->m_LocalTransform * child->m_LocalTransform;
        }

        m_FinalBoneMatrices[bone->id] = bone->globalTransform;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < bone->children.size(); i++)
        CalculateBoneTransform(bone->children[i], depth + 1);
}
```

Somehow i can't manage to update all bones correctly with it's global matrix.

The global matrix is composed of the sum of a parents children localtransform?

I have managed to animate isolated parts like the hips, legs etc succesfully but now the complete model.

I appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: I have only a little knowledge of animation, but according to forward kinetics, it seems that you need to get the global transform of the parent and propagate it to the children instead of in the reverse order.

Comment: `bone->parent->globalTransform =` will overwrite the value every iteration of the loop. If you want to combine the `globalTransform` from the previous iteration, you will need to use something like `+=` or `*=` or something like that, depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: To put it another way, your first loop will always result in `bone->m_LocalTransform * bone->children[lastChild]->m_LocalTransform`. It doesn't actually take into account the other children at all.